# Can an object tell its own position in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bunch of objects in a list

```
objectList = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    objectList.append(AnObject())
```

Given this, would there be a way to write a function within the class AnObject that returns the object's index. In pseudocode:

```
class AnObject:
    def returnIndex():
        if self in List:
           return List.index(self)
```

EDIT: In addition, I was wondering if you could have a function within a class that would remove the object from a list. This is mainly what I need the above for.

Comment: That pseudocode would probably do it, actually, if you changed `List` to `objectList` and had the mandatory `self` in the `def` line. Or are you asking "how would I do this if I didn't know the name of the list, and wasn't even sure if there were any lists anywhere that contained this object?" I don't think an object can determine every other object that refers to it.

Comment: In your particular case, yes. If the object can have duplicate references in the list, then no.

Comment: Umm.... `obj=object(); items = [obj, obj, obj, obj, obj]` - which position is object supposed to think it is exactly?

Comment: I would like to do this without the object explicitly knowing the name of the list

Comment: And `list_a = [None, obj]; list_b = [obj, None]` - now which position is it?

Comment: The only way is to store the index(es) in the object itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import uuid

class AnObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.object_id = uuid.uuid4()
        # print("created object with id: " + str(self.object_id)
    def find_me_in_list(self, a_list):
        """
        This method will find the lowest index occurrence of this 
        object in the specified list "a_list".
        :param: a list reference 
        :return: String indicating whether object was found 
        """
        try:
            pos = a_list.index(self)
            print("Found object at position: " + str(pos))
            return True
        except ValueError:
            print("Did not find this object")
            return False

    def remove_me_from_list(self, a_list):
        """
        This method will remove this object from the specified list 
 "a_list".
        The method removes all occurrences of the object from the 
 list by using a while loop
        :param: a list reference 
        :return: None
        """
        if self.find_me_in_list(a_list):
            while self in a_list:
                print("Removing this object from position " + str(a_list.index(self)) + " in list")  ### for debugging
                a_list.remove(self)
        else:
            print("object does not exist in this list")

some_obj = AnObject()
some_other_obj = AnObject()  ### we will not add this object instance to the list

objectList = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    objectList.append(AnObject())
    # print(objectList[i].object_id) ### for debugging

### let's add some_obj to objectList five times
for i in range(0, 5):
    objectList.append(some_obj)

### let's try to find these objects
some_obj.find_me_in_list(objectList)
some_other_obj.find_me_in_list(objectList)

print("***" * 20)

### let's try to delete these objects
print("let's try to delete these objects")

some_other_obj.remove_me_from_list(objectList)

some_obj.remove_me_from_list(objectList)
```